# Triggering alert when the mouseover to the browswe tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have to trigger an alert when i move the cursor to the current tab in the browser but not inside the page. for more reference i have attached the screenshot

http://pho.to/7hlXZ

Kindly help me with the issue

Comment: no such event available in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of doing this (with "just" JavaScript and in the browser itself) and as I know none of browser providers are planning on integrate such thing.

Closest as it gets (maybe): listen to "trends" in mouse coordinates that go anywhere from page body to 0 and stays out of body for more than x miliseconds.

But that would really just mean mouse is out of browser (document) and probably went to top of it...

Probably you are more interested in **window.onbeforeunload** and **Page Visibility** API - I suggest you check those two and "refurbish" your idea :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But i had already tried with Page Visibility API it does not meet my requirement. Can we do it with any other programming languages.

Comment: I understand your demand - but am afraid Visibility and onbeforeunload are max. that is offered from the browser itself and seems to also have pretty good support...

It can be done, but not within browser. But solution could be (for) complicated & expensive :

- maybe browser extensions would allow something similar (brings cross-browsers problems and client install into game),
- custom browser (for example take Firefox and add this functionality - client install),
- almost "keylogger" like software running in OS (which means client install also).